# How to combine multiple projects on publish into one folder in .NET, with ready to run and standalone?

Tags: dotnet

I'm working on a solution containing multiple projects outputting executables (Avalonia Apps) and they need to be distributed within one artifact. I'm using centralized package management to ensure that every project is using the same version of a dependency.

For now we simply run dotnet publish for each project and target the same output folder. This works totally fine but is very slow, because every time all the required dependencies are copied over and over again (and I think ready to run plays an important part too).

I'm looking for a possibility to speed this up. Can dotnet publish handle multiple executables at once? Could I combine the executable projects as dependencies in a separate project and only publish this one?